# dart function - arrow syntax confliction

Tags: dart, syntax

### 1. There is confliction on Dart Language tour

In Functions section, it says

> The => expr syntax is a shorthand for { return expr; }.
>
> Note: Only an expression—not a statement—can appear between the arrow (=>) and the semicolon (;). For example, you can’t put an if statement there, but you can use a conditional expression.

But in the Anonymous functions section, it says

> If the function contains only one statement, you can shorten it using arrow notation

Does it mean I can use statement which is not an expression (such as if statement) in anonymous functions?

```dart
var fun = () => return 3; // However, this doesn't work.
var gun = () {
  return 3;               // this works.
}
```

---

Or am I confusing concept of expression and statement? I thought

- expression : can be evaluated to a value ( 2 + 3 , print('') also falls into an expression )
- statement : code that can be executed. all expressions can be statement. if statement and return statement are examples of statement which is not expression.

### 2. Is this expression or statement

```dart
void foo() => true; // this works.
void goo() {
  return true;      // this doesn't work.
}
void hoo() {
  true;             // this works.
}
```

If true is understood as expression, then it will mean return true and I believe it should not work because foo's return type is void.

Then does it mean true in foo is understood as a statement? But this conclusion contradicts with dart language tour. (They are top-level named functions). Also, this means we can use statement with arrow syntax.

---

I use VSCode and Dart from flutter: 1.22.5. I tell code that works from code that doesn't work based on VSCode error message.

Because this is my first question, I apologize for my short English and ill-formed question.

Comment: I think that the "If the function contains only one statement, you can shorten it using arrow notation" is using "statement" in a casual and not technical sense. `=>` requires an expression on the right-hand-side.  It is true that a function with a single statement of `return 3;` can be shortened; the shortened form is `=> 3`. in practice it's rare (but not impossible) to have a function with one statement that can't be shortened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be an *expression*. The text is misleading.

For the second part, the error you see with

```dart
void foo() {
  return 0;
}
```

and not with

```dart
void bar() => 0;
```

is a *special case* for `=>` in functions returning `void`. Normally, you can't return a *value* from a function with return type `void`, so no `return exp;`, only `return;`.
(There are exceptions if `exp` has type `void`, `null` or `dynamic`, but yours doesn't).

Because people like the short-hand notation of `void foo() => anything;` so much, you are allowed to do that no matter what the type of `anything` is. That's why there is a distinction between `void foo() { return 0; }` and `void foo() => 0;`. They still mean the same thing, but the type-based error of the former is deliberately suppressed in the latter.

Comment: I found a document which clarifies this. Its context is about`=> e` (where e is an expression).  In particular, e can have any type when the return type is void. This enables concise declarations of void functions. It is reasonably easy to understand such a function, because the return type is textually near to the returned expression e.

From Dart Programming Language Specification 5th edition draft, Version 2.2.  2019.07.29.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the author of that section under Anonymous functions was a bit confused.  File an issue against it, and get it corrected!

Yeah, even in their example they use a print() function, which they might be confusing as a print "statement", which it clearly is not.

Comment: It would be nice to hear your opinion about second question, because I can not explain foo as a expression.

Comment: By the way, filed https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/2878

Comment: As for the second question, I'm guessing that `Object => void` can't literally mean "returns void", so it just works out, and the text-for-text equivalence as a block subroutine doesn't match.  I'm not gonna call that a language flaw, because it's darn convenient that it works that way. :)

Comment: @WBN `true` is an expression. `return true;` is a statement. `true;` is a statement with one expression, but the result of that expression is ignored. `void foo() => true;` works as a matter of convenience; otherwise it would be awkward to use `=>` to shorten functions that return `void`.